# how to get all the apps that can open file to arrayList

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent, filesystems

how i can get all the apps that can open file to ArrayList?
i am using this code to open file:-

```
         Intent i888777 = new Intent;
    Uri ur888 = (Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(_path)));
    i888777.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i888777.setDataAndType(ur888,_type);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i888777,_msg));
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGKcJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intead of calling `startActivity` just use `queryIntentActivities`

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i888777,
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

you can also try with `MATCH_ALL` flag or whatever you need. more to inspect in [DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)